# Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[dshm data]: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Kubernetes cluster crashing consistently due to the following error

```
Pod keycloak-postgresql-0
Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[dshm data]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

which almost certainly leads later to this error

```
Pod keycloak-postgresql-0
AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "pvc-94b61d69-b529-4b0b-bef3-4b85880a0e71" : instance not found
```

Although this instance not found error is perplexing as Rancher clearly shows that exact hash `pvc-94b61d69-b529-4b0b-bef3-4b85880a0e71`  under the "bound" state of PersistentVolumes. While I'm fairly new to k8s, this seems like the wrong error

Based on the similar nature to the error, I thought [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69544012/unable-to-attach-or-mount-volumes-timed-out-waiting-for-the-condition) would be relevant and tried creating an extra PVC to overcome the limitation but the errors persisted

At one point it was working before redeploying so the error is isolated to a cluster config issue but I have no way of figuring out comparing the previous setup to the current one

The keycloak-postgresql pod also never becomes "ready" but doesn't produce any logs even when redeployed if that info helps in any way