# PVC Failing in mounting for a Kubeadm K8s Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

For PV, I am using NFS (Network File System) server on each node(Worker and control Plane nodes).
NFS Installation and configuration is done as below;

- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server`
- `sudo mkdir /nfs-share`
- Configure NFS server: On each node, configure the NFS server to share the directory created in step 2. This is done by editing the **`/etc/exports`** file and adding the following line: `/nfs-share *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)`
- `sudo systemctl start nfs-kernel-server && sudo systemctl status nfs-kernel-server`
- PV was created using this:

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolume
  metadata:
    name: nfs-pv
  spec:
    capacity:
      storage: 1Gi
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
    nfs:
      path: /nfs-share
      server: <NFS-SERVER-IP>
  ```
- **<NFS-SERVER-IP>** is `ip addr show | grep inet`

  ```
  ip addr show | grep inet
      inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
      inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
      inet 10.0.0.179/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global enp0s3
      inet6 fe80::17ff:fe01:d25/64 scope link 
      inet 10.244.1.0/32 scope global flannel.1
      inet6 fe80::3057:20ff:fe32:9efc/64 scope link 
      inet 10.244.1.1/24 brd 10.244.1.255 scope global cni0
  ```
- The IP address of the NFS server in this output is **`10.0.0.179`**. This is the IP address assigned to the **`enp0s3`** network interface on the node and is the address that you would use as the value for **`<NFS-SERVER-IP>`** in the Persistent Volume YAML file.
- PVC created by

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    name: nfs-pvc
  spec:
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 1Gi
  ```

This is how I configured NFS on all nodes

For Testing the PV and PVC, I created an nginx-deployment file which is

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: html
              mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
        - name: html
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvc
```

My containers in the pod was not able to create and gave the below error when described

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround 1:**

Check you may have taken snapshots on the VMs before install. Having the snapshot which is active and live IO prevents making changes to disks like detach or attach disks. Try to remove html and keep html-volume, it may start again.

You can use the command like : `kubectl delete volumeattachment [volumeattachment_name]`

FailedMount is a common error in this situation that means Kubernetes is unable to detach, reattach, and mount a volume. When this happens, you may need to manually detach a disk or instruct Kubernetes Scheduler to start the Pod in a specific node.

Refer to similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69544012/unable-to-attach-or-mount-volumes-timed-out-waiting-for-the-condition) and [Blog](https://veducate.co.uk/kubelet-unable-attach-volumes/) for more information.

**Workaround 2 :**

FailedMount means a volume can’t be mounted on a specific path and can be a consequence of the previous error since the mount operation happens after attach. Because the attach operation fails, the [mount timeout expires](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/volume/attachdetach/reconciler/reconciler.go#L186), meaning the mount operation is not possible. Other reasons can be incorrect device path or device mount path.

Refer to [General discussion](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/unable-to-attach-or-mount-volumes-unmounted-volumes-code-storage/13921/3) and [Access modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) for more information.

Comment: Hello @Abdul Gaffoor Noor Basha, if you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting (✔️) or up voting it. I'd really appreciate it. Have a great day, thanks!

Comment: Hello @Abdul Gaffoor Noor Basha, Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem?, let me know I am happy to help if you have any further queries.